# escape forward slash in jsonpath

Tags: json, jsonpath, json-query, json-path-expression

I'm trying to write a simple JSON path query

```
oc get pa -o jsonpath='{range.data[*]}{@.data.vpa.pa\.poc\.hpa\\/value}{"\n"}{end}'

"data" [
      {
      "vpa"
       {
"pa.poc.hpa/value" : 20
}
}
]
```

from above JSON trying to get 20

```
 "pa.poc.hpa/value" : 20
```

i'm trying to pull 20 using below, but not getting value . giving empty results

```
pa\.poc\.hpa\\/value
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't recognize the `{}` syntax you're using.

A proper JSON Path would be

```
$.data[*].vpa['pa.poc.hpa/value']
```

The `[*]` would search all of the items in the `data` array.

Because you have a non-standard property name `pa.poc.hpa/value` you need to use the bracket syntax with the property name in quotes.